# Return array with elements in random positions

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I want the elements from the students variable to be pushed into the results array in a randomised order each time the code is ran.

I'm not sure how to do this as I am pretty new to JavaScript.

Here's my code.

```
function getRandomElement(arr){
  return arr[Math.floor((Math.random()* arr.length))];
}

var students = ['John', 'Dan', 'Jordan', 'Matt', 'Beth'];
var results = [];

for(var ) {
results.push (getRandomElement(students)); 
}
//console.log(getRandomElement(students));

console.log(results);
```

Comment: replace `for (var )` with `for(var i=0; i<students.length; i++)`

Comment: That will fix the syntax error but not make the program correct.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps. It splices a random item until the original array is empty.

```js
var students = ['John', 'Dan', 'Jordan', 'Matt', 'Beth'];
var results = [];

while (students.length) {
    results.push(students.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * students.length), 1)[0]); 
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(results, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Is it possible to return those results without using document.write? I'm trying to run this in JSBin.

Comment: yes, for example wit alert: `alert(JSON.stringify(results, 0, 4));`